# HandsomeSoup URL Fetch Issues When URL Contains Square Brackets

Tags: haskell, hxt

The following code does not work when the URL contains `[]`. Could someone tel me how to escape it? I have tried encoding the entire URL but that did not help.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Network.HTTP.Types.URI
import Text.HandsomeSoup
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

main = do
    -- This URL works (no [])
    let url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=3%2F10%2F14&test0=hello"
    --let urlEnc = B.unpack $ urlEncode True $ B.pack url
    doc <- fromUrl url
    links <- runX $ doc >>> css "a" ! "href"
    mapM_ putStrLn links
```

If I change the URL to below (note the [0]), it does not work.

```
    let url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=3%2F10%2F14&test[0]=hello"
```

By working, I mean I see a list of links when there is no `[]` but I get nothing inside `ghci` (goes to the prompt) when there is `[]` in the URL. If you copy the second URL and paste it in your browswer, it works just fine, however.

I made this example up to illustrate the issue with `[]`. Of course, it is not a valid URL given by Google or anything.

GHC: 7.6.2, Mac OS X (Mavericks)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the `urlEncode` does nothing to `[` and `]` because it should not, they are not special in general.

You can however encode them using `%5B` and `%5D` ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)), so an alternative would be to manually replace `[` and `]` in your url.